# VB.net: Custom ' TODO: List on an Interface

Tags: vb.net, comments

How do I add my own todo and comments list to appear on Interfaces? I want it to pop up like IDisposable does:

```
Public Class Foo : Implements IDisposable

    Private disposedValue As Boolean = False        ''# To detect redundant calls

    ''# IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                ''# TODO: free other state (managed objects).
            End If

            ''# TODO: free your own state (unmanaged objects).
            ''# TODO: set large fields to null.
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

#Region " IDisposable Support "
    ''# This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ''# Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Whenever I enter my own comments and todo list they are never autogenerated like IDisposable Interface does. I would like my own Interfaces to preserve the comments so that I can share my Interfaces with in source documentation.

Comment: To my knowledge, that’s not possible. At least it wasn’t several years ago where I inquired this problem. VS 2010 may have added support, though.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: That is too bad that because that would be a great documentation feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is hard-baked into Common7\IDE\msvb7.dll.  Pretty shocking, considering how totally inappropriate it is for the 99.99% of cases where you'd want to implement IDisposable.

Consider using code snippets.  You can create your own snippets with the [Snippet Editor](http://snippeteditor.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I suppose there is no way to "hardbake" our own Class Libraries with commets?

Comment: The example you showed isn't a comment.  But no, beyond snippets or writing your own macro, you have no way to change the way the editor automatically generates code.