# Adding annotations to interfaces

Tags: vb.net, interface

I've seen cases in the .NET framework where, when you implement an interface, visual studio generates comments (and other goodies like regions).

A good example would be `IDisposable`. When you implement it, visual studio generates the following code block:

```
#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            End If

            ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
            ' TODO: set large fields to null.
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' TODO: override Finalize() only if Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region
```

Is this something I can do in my own code? If so, how? I would like to add a few comments to my interface's methods telling the implementer what the general purpose of the method is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.net: Custom ' TODO: List on an Interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884036/vb-net-custom-todo-list-on-an-interface)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is 100% what you were asking but here goes.

Above your method definition type '''

The editor expands that out into a piece of XML that is used to drive the intellisense when that method is used.

```
Private Sub Import(ByVal ImportFileName As String, ByRef OutFileName As String)
```

becomes

```
''' <summary>
''' Imports data from import file into Output File
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ImportFileName">the fully qualified path to the import file</param>
''' <param name="OutFileName">the fully qualified path for the output file</param>
''' <remarks>all the widgets need to be thoroughly castigated</remarks>
Private Sub Import(ByVal ImportFileName As String, ByRef OutFileName As String)
```

And whenever this Import method is used the hints provided are presented alongside the names of the parameters.

Comment: It's probably the closest I'll ever get, but I'm really looking for a way to provide inline code documentation for my interfaces. Only the programmer who writes the implementation should ever get to see them, not everyone who consumes it.

Comment: If you've ever written a class in VB that implements `IDisposable`, you'll know what I mean. As soon as you add the interface, you get a default implementation sprinkled with TODO comments. This is exactly the sort of thing I want to do.

Comment: I have used the IDisposable interface and know exactly what your mean. But According to the linked question above that lovely TODO stuff for IDisposable is hard coded into the VS editor. and your best course is to have snippets,

Comment: I'd be surprised if it was completely impossible to write a visual studio add-in that does something similar. Of course you'd need to install it on every development machine, which is not something I can expect from my users.